Display turning off causes power failure
I built a new pc and after adding the GPU, noticed that pc loses power shortly after display is turned off by power options due to inactivity. I used the same pc with the igpu only for a week where i didn't face this issue.
In the event viewer there is only a entry about unexpected power failure/shutdown.
Any suggestions to troubleshoot this issue is appreciated.
Pc parts:
Ryzen 5 5600x ,
MSI B650S wifi ,
Gigabyte RTX 4070 windforce ,
G Skill Flare x5 ram

So, you are not turning the screen off yourself, but it is being turned off by the system power settings? Typically, you should check for updated drivers and firmware as a first step troubleshooting this sort of thing. Also, check that your PSU is appropriately sized for your components.

Can you replicate this issue any other way? For example - manually turning off your monitor, putting your PC to sleep, etc. Also I'd recommend re-inserting the GPU + making sure the power cable is plugged all the way into it and the PSU, as well as updating GPU and monitor drivers.

GPU drivers are up to date, only chipset/igpu drivers were not up to date and I updated them now. Fault is only there if it is left unattended/inactive for a period of time. (Sleep is set to never). I have 650W Corsair PSU and tried several benchmarks to stress test. Didn't face this issue during the benchmark. I also tried reseating the GPU and cables after first fault which didn't help. I will update if chipset drivers made any difference.

Verify in Event Viewer under Windows Logs > System, is pc loosing power or just cant wake out of whatever sleep it triggers(once or for each that event?). You say your sleep is set to off, is there a pattern in minutes of inactivity when this is triggered?
